# Has Contact ID been removed from the Contact Import "Matching"?

Tags: import

I have a v strong memory, and screenshot evidence that we used to be able to 'match' by including the Contact ID in the import.

This was discussed in https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/sjht4rjsxifwtk6iofe3a19ftw and here is the screenshot I have which I used to explain to a client how to do this back in Nov 2018 (haven't dug out the version but would have been as least the Security Release that was current at the time.

[image]

No such field shows on dmaster, and nor does eg 'internal id' or any other variation I could think of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the first step you have to check "update" where it says For duplicate contacts.

Comment: ah ha - when i checked on dmaster yes it was defaulted to 'skip' and i ignored that